# Angular 2 maturity: going in prod with usable components

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-grid

I am looking to build a new set of web apps, and I have been working already with Angular v1.x, [Angular UI Grid 3.0](http://ui-grid.info/) & other common components (Angular UI Bootstrap, Slider...).

Angular 2 seems mature enough to be used today, but my question is more on components I need around it:

- only references I found so far of usable grids are [AG Grid](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid), and [Angular UI Grid 4.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4294), which is not yet on tracks,
- other components such as [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/wiki/Roadmap) are in *alpha* stage, and some other Angular UI project have not yet stated to be ported.

---

**Disclaimer**: I am **not** asking for opinions on v1.x vs v2.x here.

---

Not being knowledgeable on Angular 2, I would like to know:

- If you are going in production today building apps on Angular 2, what is your **approach**?
- What **basic components** you are using (grid, navigation, slider) and if they are v2 ready,
- How difficult is it to run v1 & v2 Angular code **side-by-side**?
- How difficult is it to use **non-TypeScript** components in v2?

Comment: Have you written any v2? imho it is not mature...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ag-Grid is written in typescript. it is ng2 ready with regards it can work perfectly with ng2. we have just released ng2 cellRendering (so you can use angular 2 inside you cells) and are working on cellEditing (will be ready in the coming days). regards v1 and v2 side by side, i have no idea, however ag-Grid works with both ng1 and ng2, so if you have an app with ag-Grid, you will have an easier time moving from ng1 to ng2 as the grid will be the same.

not exactly your specific questions, but i think you might find this useful information.

Comment: Thanks for the point on ag-Grid, but I was hoping of a broader state-of-the art type of answer